# Stopping Page Loading - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I unfortunately can not stop a page from loading using Selenium in Python.

I have tried:

1. `driver.execute_script("window.stop();")`
2. `driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)`
3. `webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()`

The page is a .cgi that constantly loads. I would like to either scrape data from a class on the page or the page title, however neither works with the 3 methods above.

When I try to manually press ESC, or click the cross, it works perfectly.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your code and a page you are working on, so we can only guess.
So, in case you really tried all the above **correctly** and it still not helped try adding `Eager` page loading strategy to your driver options.
`Eager` [page loading strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/) will make WebDriver wait until the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, and discards loading of stylesheets, images and subframes (DOMContentLoaded event fire is returned).

With it your code will look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# Navigate to url
driver.get(your_page_url)
```

**UPD**
You are trying to upload a file with Selenium and doing it wrong.
To upload the file with Selenium you need to send a full file path to that element.
So, if the file you want to upload is located by `C:/Model.lp` your code should be:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='field.1']").send_keys("C:/Model.lp")
```

Comment: Hi I really appreciate your reply, unfortunately the webpage never loads into a .html. It loads literally forever. Any other ideas? I've deduced that: 'driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click()' is the line that never finishes executing.

Comment: We are still missing too much details here, sorry.

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver.exe)
driver.get("https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/milp:CPLEX/LP.html")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='field.1']").send_keys("Model.lp")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='priority']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']").send_keys("email")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click()
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")`

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: I appreciate your help but the upload works perfectly. The submit button is what stalls. I just edited the Model.lp and email to remove identifying information.

Comment: OK, I'll try to debug that later